# Collectionview CustomLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I want a collectionview cell should be the dynamic height. I am getting data from server and loading in to tableview inside collectionview cell. That cell height should be change according to the table cell height, I am getting till here. But the problem is The cells are not aligning from the top. see this  pic.  The cell should create from top. [This is demo code](https://www.facebook.com/groups/indianiosteam/739322239431990/). Thanks

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=652366928166381&set=p.652366928166381&type=1 this is my image reference

Comment: Don't put your code behind a link that requires a sign in. Add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, try setting self.yourCollectionView.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

Answer (score 0):

You will need to extend UICollectionViewLayout. And then in the prepareLayout method, you will need to specify the calculated frames of every item of your collectionview.
There are two tutorials:
http://www.skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial is a very good tutorial for custom layout.

https://github.com/betzerra/MosaicLayout and  https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/rfquiltlayout is pretty much what you want. A related question about rfquiltlayout on stackoverflow is [RFQuiltLayout and UICollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21664555/rfquiltlayout-and-uicollectionview)