# UicollectionViewCell not showing up after changing the Layout to custom class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm using [RFQuiltLayout](https://github.com/bryceredd/RFQuiltLayout) in for my `uicollectionview`.

My storyboard contain `Uiview` + `collectionview`. collectionview are `IBOutleted` to my `UiView` class and in my storyboard i'm using custom layout for my collectionview like this :

[image]

I'm loading my collectionview data from `appdelegate` class so in first run it return `0` for `numberOfItemsInSection` and after data get fetched from server it will load my collectionview.

Now problem is if i change the Layout to flow program works correctly but if i use custome class like `RFQuiltLayout` no cell shows up ,

**numberOfItemsInSection** returns my actual value but **cellForItemAtIndexPath** not getting called.

The code in my `ViewDidLoad`:

```
   self.CV.delegate = self;
    self.CV.dataSource = self;
    [self.CV registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

    RFQuiltLayout* layout = (id)[self.CV collectionViewLayout];
    layout.direction = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
    layout.blockPixels = CGSizeMake(75,75);
```

I'm also calling `reloaddata` in `viewDidAppear`.

and in `appdelegate`:

```
   ParseOperation *weakParser = parser;
    parser.completionBlock = ^(void) {
        if (weakParser.appRecordList) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

           MyCollectionViewController *rootViewControllers = (MyCollectionViewController*)[(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController topViewController];
                rootViewControllers.entries = weakParser.appRecordList;
               [rootViewControllers.CV.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout]; 
               [rootViewControllers.CV reloadData];
            });
        }
```

one thing is if i use this code in my delegate the uicollection shows up but without any custome layout and scrolling ability :

```
            [rootViewControllers.CV reloadData];
            NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            NSIndexPath *indexPath;
            for (int i = 0; i < [weakParser.appRecordList count]; i++) {
                indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0];
                [indexPaths addObject:indexPath];
            }

            [rootViewControllers.CV reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
```

the methods inside RFQuiltLayout gets called but the method for layout inside

uiview like these "**blockSizeForItemAtIndexPath**" and

"**blockSizeForItemAtIndexPath**" not getting called.

Comment: You probably need to create the layout. Check out [this post][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21664555/rfquiltlayout-and-uicollectionview

Comment: i dont think thats the case because collection view and its layout have been initialised from a storyboard.also i put some nslog inside layout and the layout functions are called inside RFQuiltLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to register the class again in your didload. I guess this is the reason behind your issue. Go to you Storyboard and select your `CollectionViewCell` and change its class to your custom class. And remove this line from your didLoad `[self.CV registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];`